# Port forwarding for VNC on Dynalink RTA1335 not working

Tags: router, vnc, port, adsl, forwarding

I've vnc-java running on an Ubuntu box, with the IP address 192.168.1.68, using port 5800 (because port 5900 is being used for normal VNC).

If I connect to 192.168.1.68:5800 using another computer on the network, I can use VNC fine.

Using www.whatismyip.com, I find out what my IP address from the outside world is, and if I go directly to that, I get to access my modem/router.  If I try to navigate to that IP address, with ':5800' on the end, I get a "This web page is not available." error.

I have port forwarding set up in the router as follows:

```
Application Name    External Packet             Internal Host
                 IP Address     Protocol    Port    IP Address      Port    
VNC                  ALL        TCP/UDP     5800    192.168.1.68    5800
```

What else do I need to do to get this to work?

Comment: I'm wondering if the modem/router was provided by the ISP and they may have locked things down or maybe running some kind of server side firewall.  Also it sounds like you can get to the modem/router's management interface from the public address, if so, that sounds like trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Your router is probably forwarding packets received on its external interface to 192.168.1.68, if you are accessing it internally then it won't forward. This is common with most home routers.

You can test for port forwarding using a site like [Can You See Me?](http://www.canyouseeme.org)